# Убегающая кнопка WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

При наведении курсора на кнопку, она должна смещаться на случайное расстояние, но не за границы окна. Как можно сделать, чтобы кнопка не возвращалась к исходному положению, а продолжала перемещение с той, координаты, куда переместилась в результате предыдущей анимации?

```
private void decraseMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(20, 100);
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        decraseButton.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation daX = new DoubleAnimation(0, decraseButton.ActualWidth+x, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty,daX);
        DoubleAnimation daY = new DoubleAnimation(0, decraseButton.ActualHeight+x, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, daY);
    }
```

Comment: `но не за границы окна` - ну так сверяйте текущие размеры окна и положение кнопки, если положение кнопки + ее размеры больше размеров окна, то она за пределами. `чтобы кнопка не возвращалась к исходному положению` - убрать у анимации `From`? То есть, вот вы пишете `new DoubleAnimation(0, decraseButton.ActualHeight+x, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` - дословно это будет так: "Плавно изменить `double` значение с `0` до `decraseButton.ActualHeight+x` за 1 сек.", а если уберете `0` (From), то анимация будет брать текущее значение свойства, а не 0.

Comment: убрал 0, однако, при повторном наведении на кнопку, она обратно возвращается на место, где была изначально, а не продолжает с того места, куда переместилась в результате предыдущей анимации(

Comment: Тогда еще уберите постоянное `decraseButton.RenderTransform = trans;`, вы кнопке делаете вечно "дефольные" здачения. Вынесите это в конструктор окна, допустим `decraseButton.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();`, а в анимации не `trans`, а `decraseButton.RenderTransform`. А лучше, научитесь делать это все через XAML, ибо в коде, в WPF проекте, не делает кто-либо контролы. У вас в C# должно быть только `int x = rnd.Next(20, 100);`, все. остальное в XAML.